# Where can I find the list of contacts that have opted in for push notifications via the API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobilepush, marketingcloudapi, event-notification-service

In the mobile push rest API, is there somewhere where I can find the list of contacts that has opted in to receive push notifications via the API?
Also, is there a way, say via the Event Notification Server, where it is broadcast to a webhook that someone has opted in?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can also retrieve this information via API by searching by the Attribute named "MobilePush Demographics", with the route:

```
/contacts/v1/attributeSets/name:MobilePush%20Demographics/search
Example:
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
POST /contacts/v1/attributeSets/name:MobilePush%20Demographics/search
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
"request": {
"attributes": [{
"key": "MobilePush Demographics.Device ID"
}]
},
"conditionSet": {
"operator": "And",
"conditionSets": [],
"conditions": [{
"attribute": {
"key": "MobilePush Demographics.Device ID"
},
"operator": "Equals",
"value": {
"items": ["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
}
}]
}
}
Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/attributeSetsDataName.htm
```

Comment: Is this the only way to know who is and who is not a mobile subscriber irrespective of device id?